# Android, LayoutInflater, ошибка

Tags: android-sdk

Помогите решить проблему. Запускаю приложение и выдает ошибку "приложение остановлено". Пытался вычислить ошибку путем расстановки меток логом, но лог вообще молчит (даже onCreate)... Пытался переносить инициализацию в onCreate, но результата ноль. Где я мог допустить ошибку?

Вот код:

```
**//MainActivity.java
package com.example.lesson41project1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        final String LOG = "APP";
        String[] name = {"Иван", "Вова", "Дима", "Женя", "Катя", "Оля", "Костя", "Вася"};
        String[] position = {"директор", "программист", "бухгалтер", "программист", "менеджер", "бухгалтер", "аниматор", "менеджер"};
        int[] salary = {10000, 15000, 13000, 23000, 32000, 2200, 10000, 2300};
        int[] colors = new int[2];


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                Log.i(LOG, "старт onCreate");

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                Log.i(LOG, "Присваивание цветов");
                colors[0] = Color.parseColor("#559966CC");
                colors[1] = Color.parseColor("#55336699");

                Log.i(LOG, "Создание LinearLayout и LayoutInflater");
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
                LayoutInflater lInflater = getLayoutInflater();

                Log.i(LOG, "Старт цикла");
                for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
                        Log.i(LOG, "Запуск inflate");
                        View item = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, ll, false);

                        Log.i(LOG, "Инициализация TextView");
                        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                        TextView tvPosition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPosition);
                        TextView tvSalary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);

                        Log.i(LOG, "Создание нужных значений TextView");
                        tvName.setText(name[i]);
                        tvPosition.setText("Должность: " + position[i]);
                        tvSalary.setText("Зарплата: " + salary[i]);

                        Log.i(LOG, "Настройка width и цветов");
                        item.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                        item.setBackgroundColor(colors[i%2]);

                        Log.i(LOG, "Добавление View");
                        ll.addView(item);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                        return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}





//activty_main.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Staff list" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>





//item.xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPosition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSalary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</FrameLayout>**
```

P.S. Кому легче, вот он на pastebin - http://pastebin.ru/SB13fdVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка заключается в том, что при заполнении `LinearLayout` элементами вы ищите свои `TextView` в разметке `activity`, хотя их надо искать в разметке `item.xml`. Т.е. должно быть так:

```
Log.i(LOG, "Инициализация TextView");
TextView tvName = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
TextView tvPosition = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvPosition);
TextView tvSalary = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);
```

Кстати в `LogCat` выводился достаточно подробный лог, глядя на который проблему можно было исправить за пару минут.

И еще, почему бы не использовать `ListView` для вывода списка работников?

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чем ошибка. Я смотрел в LogCat (специально расставлял метки), но видимо что-то не так в нем настроил и он "молчал". До ListView я еще не дошел.